# How To Find the Site Statistics

Tags: support, statistics

I am interested in monitoring the growth of this site but I noticed that the Questions Per Day wasn't included in the little sidebar (example below).
[image: Site Stats 08/01/16]

How can I find more in depth site statistics than this on this site? Or on any SE site for that matter?

Comment: you can get the QPD number by going here.  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1321/motor-vehicle-maintenance-and-repair

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can access some data without 5000 Rep.  You'll find out real quick once you go there.  Here is the location for the data explorer.
[Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/)

I do not believe there are any site analytic available here though. As Zaid said you need 5K Rep to get access to that data.  At your rate, you should be there pretty quickly though.

Comment: Yes I was just curious as to how many questions there were yesterday but I guess you get all that sort of info at 5k presumably?

Comment: you can go here and get the QPD number    http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1321/motor-vehicle-maintenance-and-repair

Comment: Yes I did see that, though it is an average as opposed to one particular day, it could have both - no big deal though

Comment: Yes, you have access to site analytics at 5K rep.

Comment: Did you attempt to access the data explorer?  Does it let you play?   http://data.stackexchange.com/mechanics/queries

Comment: I don't know I just get a list of "All Queries", I don't really see any stats.

Answer (score 3):

The Questions Per Day statistic is mentioned in Area 51.

Click on the Area 51 link to see the QPD statistic.

You can gain access to [Site Analytics](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) once you have 5,000 reputation points.